# When connecting to URL from browser I am not getting authentication but when hitting the URL from Java code Http 401 Error is coming

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

**https://www.cbz.com** Link when pasted in IE or chrome Doesn't ask for authentication but when I write java code hitting the same URL I get Error 401.
I am in client's network and i don't know his credentials but I still want to hit the URL and generate the token.
Note :I do not provide Username Password of the client in httpurlconnection and want the functionality like the browsers(i.e without asking for uid/pwd).

Anything shared by anyone will be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the crediantials, either use single signon using providers like SiteMinder or an LDAP authentication.

Comment: The thing is when i am hitting the url through a browser I am able to generate the token without providing credentials but when I am writing java code i am getting 401.I am in a client's environment.